# When to use disk cleanup

Tags: hard-drive, disk-cleanup

How often should you do a disk cleanup and when you do what should you delete?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a big fan of the Windows Disk Cleanup feature. I run the freeware [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) (formerly CrapCleaner) to clean things up every week or so. It depends on what I've been doing, since some activities create a lot of temporary files. When you have a lot of temporary files, performance can be affected noticeably, which is the main reason I clean things up regularly.

The default settings in CCleaner go slightly too far in my opinion, so I always disable a few categories, leaving it configured to delete the following:

- **Internet Explorer** > Temporary Internet files
- **System** > Empty Recycle Bin
- **System** > Temporary files
- **Firefox/Mozilla** > Internet cache
- **Opera** > Internet cache
- **Google Chrome** > Internet cache

Comment: Note that you should also consider defragmenting after a long clean. But CCleaner is the best

Answer (score 0):

I don't use much anymore, mainly because I do manual cleanup myself.

Options I Never use to use in XP disk cleanup is Compress old files, Downloaded Program Files, Office Setup Files.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would only do it when low on space - then choose delete whatever I do not need.

Easy ones to free up space: `Temporary internet files` and `Recycle Bin`

You can also choose all the log file ones if you are not currently having any problems / you do not read them.

Finally there is the ability to compress hard drive - only do that if you are desperate for space as it can slow down the machine (marginally).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that CCleaner is the better way however I do use Disk Cleanup to clean old restore points just before I make or update a disk image for backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should use too tuneup utility and one good tool called [Advanced SystemCare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_SystemCare).

It will keep your computer very fast by cleaning the junk files and more option in this software.

Answer (score 0):

You should do disk cleanup at every week, 
and you don't need worry what should you delete. Use `CCleaner`, `ECleaner` or `disk clean up` utility by windows. It will automatically do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use CCleaner as my tool of choice. I don't run it as often as I should, but around once every couple weeks at the moment. I tend to remove things like internet cache, temp files, recycle bin.

I am coming to the point of not deleting internet temps to often now. Since they take up no room in the grand scheme of things, all removing them will do is slow down websites you visit. Can remove them every know and then, but no point going OTT with it.